# How to add !important into React inline CSS style

Tags: css, reactjs

How to add `!important` into my inline CSS property?
If I add it after `2px` it just ignore whole style.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Todo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {text} = this.props;

        const cardStyles = {
            borderWidth: '2px'
        };

        return (
            <div class="card mb-2 border" style={cardStyles}>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title m-0">{text}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: try to define `cardStyles` as just a string like `'border-width: 2px !important'` and then instead of `style={cardStyles}'` add `style="{cardStyles}"`

Comment: Please show how you included it. It might also help to show the rendered html. [This is also worth a read](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently it is not supported https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881#issuecomment-262257503

meanwhile you can use a hack doing:

```
        <div ref={element => { 
             if (element) element.style.setProperty('border', '2px', 'important'); 
           }}
        />
```

Comment: Inline styling has a higher order than `!important`, so technically you don't need `!important`

Comment: @AnhPham Nope... I have styles from bootstrap  and they rewriting my inline style

Comment: I haven't been able to get this solution to work yet. https://codesandbox.io/s/1rrpxryjx4

Comment: ^ because its style.setProperty no setProperty @DanCron

Comment: Thanks, @ncubica. Fixing my typo from element.setProperty to element.style.setProperty worked.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it currently isn't supported based on this GitHub issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881

Comment: Trivialy easy to implement... 4 years ago...Starting thinking, that React was not best 2k18 framework to learn

Comment: Yeah agreed it seems like a massive oversight. I get the whole best practice is to avoid !important but there are plenty of use cases where it is required.

Comment: @Baterka you didn't do a wrong choice React is the leading framework, just happened that you are trying to implement an edge case I have been using react almost 3 years and this is the first time I see this particular need.